# elegant solution in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```py
sample_size = 100000
z = np.random.randn(sample_size)
```

What would be an elegant way to say:

```py
if z >= 0: f = 1 + z

if z < 0:  f = 1 / (2 - z)
```

Comment: What do you mean elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use masking:

```
np.where(z>=0, 1+z, 1/(2-z))
```